# Typescript generates declaration d.ts file with `#private;` field

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a library, written in Typescript, that is being distributed in 2 files: a compiled ECMAScript-2015 compatible Javascript file `index.js` and a Typescript declaration file `index.d.ts`. My goal is to make library accessible for both Javascript and Typescript developers (so that they have proper typings and autocomplete).

Lately I have upgraded to Typescript 3.9.7, and decided to refactor my code to use new private class fields declaration that utilizes `#` sigil instead of Typescript's `private` keyword.

To my surprise, my `index.d.ts` file become non-compatible with old Typescript versions due to including the `#private;` member on my classes.

Here is a comparison between old Typescript code generating old declaration file, and a new refactored Typescript code that generates a new non-compatible declaration file. The old code utilizing `private` keyword:

```
// index.ts
class MyClass {
    private field1: string = "foo";
    private field2: string = "bar";

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.field1, this.field2);
    }
}

// generated index.d.ts
declare class MyClass {
    private field1;
    private field2;
    constructor();
}
```

The new refactored code that uses `#` sigil to declare private names:

```
// index.ts
class MyClass {
    #field1: string = "foo";
    #field2: string = "bar";

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.#field1, this.#field2);
    }
}

// generated index.d.ts
declare class MyClass {
    #private;
    constructor();
}
```

Here is [a page at Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQMQDMBLAUxABMBGALmggBcAnQgOwHNoBeaAInwHs+3ANxYcBEuQBMNekzaceAIzANhGUdmB9msgK7A6fBgAoAlOg05N2iHxDEAdCD6tjdABaEID8aUoAaaA8vHyI-SVMRKwBfDGigA) that contains that sample code.

Now, if my customer that uses an old Typescript (let's say, version 3.7) will fetch my library (consisting of compiled `index.js` and declaration file `index.d.ts`, without the source `index.ts` file) and rely on `index.d.ts` types, they'll see the following error:

```
error TS1127: Invalid character.
```

The origin of that error is clear (the `#` sigil), so my questions are following:

1. Is it okay if I postprocess my `index.d.ts` and remove the `#private;` line before I ship my library to customers, that don't have to know about implementation details? I can easily do that by using `ttsc` package, but I still worry that piece of typing information might be somehow important.
2. What is the practical use for `#private;` line in `index.d.ts`? Why would a declaration file expose that a class utilizes private fields, if they can't be accessed anyway, and are implementation details?
3. According to [a topic in Typescript Github issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38050), this is the intended behavior so that classes with private fields retain their nominal typing behavior when emitted to a `.d.ts` file. Sadly, the meaning of that explanation slips away from me. Is there any extra documentation I can read to better understand the nominal typing behavior of Typescript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It makes the type "nominal" so that other types which expose the same public members are not seen as compatible with a type that has a private field. One case where this matters is if you have code like this:

```
class C {
    #foo = "hello";
    bar = 123;

    static log(instance: C) {
        console.log("foo = ", instance.#foo, " bar = ", instance.bar);
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are more examples, but this static method is just one that came to my head.

This `C.log` function requires an actual instance of the `C` class since it accesses a private-named instance field on the `instance` parameter. If the declaration emit doesn't reflect that the `C` type is nominal by indicating that it has an ES private field and instead only emits the public fields, the compiler will use structural type comparisons here and won't produce the expected type errors. For example, that declaration emit would allow dependent code to pass in `{ bar: 456 }` to `C.log` without any compiler error.

Comment: Indeed I tried with another `Test` class which compiles to the same `.d.ts` than your example class (same public members, different private members) and when I type `C.log(new Test);` I get *Property '#private' in type 'Test' refers to a different member that cannot be accessed from within type 'C'.*. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: I asked a moderator to merge my question with this one (the original one) so you can be eligible for the bounty

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer your question but was unable to, then I asked my own question out of curiosity, which was answered by a TypeScript contributor, you can find his answer here: [What's the purpose of #private in TypeScript definition files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823219/whats-the-purpose-of-private-in-typescript-definition-files#answer-64827614)

To summarize, there are some cases where private fields matter when it comes to the comparison between to types, that's why the `#private` field appears so that the information "contains private members" is part of the type definition.

Answer (score -3):

#private syntax is currently a [stage-3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods) for javascript. Once browsers support it then it won't be transpiled by typescript.

Comment: The question isn't what private fields are. It's what the mysterious `#private` member in the emitted definition is.

Comment: ahh...so it sounds like instead your question is "how do I emit backwards compatible typescript definition files"...I'm guessing Typescript is assuming declaration file consumers will understand that syntax.